# Cryptographic assumptions with bilinear pairings

Tags: pairings, hardness-assumptions

I have two statements which I think are correct:

1. $\beta, s$ are unknown.
   Only $g^\beta$ is known to the prover but not any of $g^{\beta s^i}$ for $i \ge 1$.
   If the prover is able to find group elements $A$ and $B$ such that $e(A, g^\beta) = e(B, g)$ then the prover knows a field element $a$ such that $A = g^a$
2. And a more general statement: $\alpha, s$ are unknown to the prover.
   $g^\alpha, g^{\alpha s}, g^{\alpha s^2}, \dots ,g^{\alpha s^q}$ are known to the prover. If the prover is able to provide group elements $A$ and $B$ such that $e(A, g^\alpha) = e(B, g)$ then the prover knows coefficients $a_i$ such that $A = g^{\sum^q_{i=0}{a_i}\alpha s^i}$

Both of these statements intuitively seem correct to me but what are the commonly used cryptographic assumptions that I should reduce them to and how should I do that?

Comment: It does not invalidate it as in your example the prover knows a = 1 and that's what the statement is about. So you have to know some a

Comment: Sorry, I misread.

Comment: Actually, for a type 1 pairing, finding $A, B$ is easy: $A = g, B = g^\beta$

Answer (score 0):

I think that both statements are untrue.

If the prover is furnished by a third party (who does not need to know $\alpha$) with $R=g^r$ and $S=g^{\alpha r}$) but not $\alpha$, then they can pick any $x$ and set $A=R^x$, $B=S^x$ without knowing $a=rx$.

In particular a malicious prover could obtain such values from a pair provided by a legitimate prover.

Comment: however this is exactly what is stated. Prover knows x. So the statement is that this is the only way to obtain the pair

Comment: @NikolayZakirov: No it is not. The prover does know $x$ but this does not furnish them with the knowledge of $a$ such that $g^a=A$.

Comment: You are right, but I think the problem is that you allow a 3d party into the universe which is not really allowed. I guess I should rewrite my statements in terms of "there exists a polynomial time extractor that given same inputs as prover has which are $g$ and $g^{\beta}$ produces $a$ such that $A=g^a$. I think this is called knowledge of exponent assumption?